# Why doesn't calling an undefined property tigger error?

Tags: javascript, object, properties

I wonder if

```
var myVar = unDef;
```

triggers an ReferenceError, why

```
var myObj = {};
var myVar = myObj.unDef;
```

works fine? It returns `undefined` without a runtime error. Both aren't defined.

Comment: because `... = unDef` is an undefined VARIABLE, while an undefined property isn't quite as serious a thing.

Comment: It’s just how the language works, like how PHP will let you use undefined variables and how Python won’t let you use unassigned properties.

Answer (score 0):

This allows you to use

```
if (myVar.unDef)
```

rather than the more verbose (and more expensive, because it calls a function):

```
if (myVar.hasOwnProperty('unDef'))
```